# Why does Chrome keep displaying "Site cannot be installed: the page is not served from a secure origin" in the console?

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker

Whenever I look in Chrome's console, I see this error message:

> Site cannot be installed: the page is not served from a secure origin

This only started happening a few days ago, and Chrome wasn't updated in the meantime.

Answer (score 5):

**2019-Dec update**: this answer is outdated. Neither of the two flags mentioned in it are available in Chrome any more. Old answer below.

---

This error is caused by sites served over HTTP if "Add to shelf" is enabled in chrome://flags.

Solution: go to `chrome://flags/#enable-app-banners` (used to be `chrome://flags/#enable-add-to-shelf`) and change "Enabled" to "Default", then relaunch Chrome.

Comment: After changing this option and reloading Chrome I still get this error.

Comment: on Chrome 65 on macOS High Sierra, there is no enable-add-to-shelf

Answer (score 0):

In later versions of Chrome, this can occur as a result of a flag relating to banner content serving. These flags change all the time, but here's how it looks in Chrome 78:

[image]

The flag is bypass-app-banner-engagement-checks, and it's pretty far down the screen (unless it's enabled, in which case it's near the top of the screen).