# Site cannot be installed: the page is not served from a secure origin

Tags: google-chrome, http, web, https

I have created *manifest.json* to a site to enable to save the web app icon on a desktop.

My developer website is over HTTP - Which doesn't work when I click on add to home screen from application tab.

I am getting console error:

> Site cannot be installed: the page is not served from a secure origin

The same code works over HTTPS.

How can I simply bypass this issue in HTTP?

Note : I have followed the following step in chrome browser, it didn't resolve my issue:
[Stackoverflow previously Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41863050/why-does-chrome-keep-displaying-site-cannot-be-installed-the-page-is-not-serve)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was service workers will only register and install on the secure origin. So followed following steps:

1. Go to *chrome.exe* path in the program files create shortcut of the chrome on the desktop
2. right click on the shortcut - Go to properties - update the target with the below changes
   `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://wzy.xyz.com,http://x.xyz.com --user-data-dir=/anydirectory/`

Note: Make sure that you google chrome executable file is present in the above mentioned location.

Also this is only to test in the local environment.

Answer (score 14):

`chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` 
enabled and add  site origin