# Android manifest simulation over https gives me an error

Tags: ssl, https, android-manifest, google-chrome-devtools, progressive-web-apps

I've just installed an ssl certificate and the website is now available over https.
On the remote host there is a manifest file for "add to home button" but when I try to simulate it through the Chrome Developer Tools - Application section I get an error saying:

> Site cannot be installed: the page is not served from a secure origin

I tried the solution proposed here [Why does Chrome keep displaying "Site cannot be installed: the page is not served from a secure origin" in the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41863050/why-does-chrome-keep-displaying-site-cannot-be-installed-the-page-is-not-serve) but nothing changed since my setting were already: default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried opening the [Security panel](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/security) on the page? It may be able to provide more info. Perhaps it's a mixed content issue (where the page is secure, but it requests insecure resources).

Comment: i'm going to try this because I can see some mixed content warnings due to the <img src=...></img> tags.

Comment: It was a mixed content issue. Thank you!